# Error in exposing ruby with passenger on a subdirectory (apache)

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I have a problem with exposing a ruby app with passengers.
I have everything installed and working on localhost:3000, and no problem accessing it.

However, I would like to expose the site on the port 80 and on a specific address: localhost/vocab

I set Apache virtualhost to expose both a current hosted website (/var/www/html/Skosmos) and the ruby app (in /var/www/html/vocab):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html/Skosmos>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ServerName domaine.fr/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 Alias vocab/ /var/www/html/vocab/public
    <Location /vocab>
        PassengerBaseURI /vocab
        PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/vocab/

    </Location>
    <Directory /var/www/html/vocab/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

but if I go to localhost/vocab I get this error

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information

my apache2/error.log report this error:

```
App 98561 stderr: Started GET "/vocab/en.html" for 193.50.232.240 at 2017-06-10 11:11:20 +0200
App 98561 stderr: Processing by FrontpageController#index as HTML
App 98561 stderr:   Parameters: {"lang"=>"en"}
App 98561 stderr:   Rendered frontpage/_title.html.erb (0.1ms)
App 98561 stderr:   Rendered frontpage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
App 98561 stderr:   Rendered layouts/_modals.html.erb (0.1ms)
App 98561 stderr:   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (4.0ms)
App 98561 stderr: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
App 98561 stderr:
App 98561 stderr: ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find table 'concepts'):
App 98561 stderr:     10:
App 98561 stderr:     11:     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
App 98561 stderr:     12:       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
App 98561 stderr:     13:         <%= nav_items Iqvoc.navigation_items %>
App 98561 stderr:     14:       </ul>
App 98561 stderr:     15:
App 98561 stderr:     16:       <%= render "layouts/controls" %>
App 98561 stderr:   app/models/concept/skos/scheme.rb:39:in `instance'
App 98561 stderr:   app/models/ability.rb:7:in `initialize'
App 98561 stderr:   app/controllers/concerns/controller_extensions.rb:95:in `new'
App 98561 stderr:   app/controllers/concerns/controller_extensions.rb:95:in `current_ability'
App 98561 stderr:   lib/iqvoc/configuration/core.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Core>'
App 98561 stderr:   app/helpers/navigation_helper.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
App 98561 stderr:   app/helpers/navigation_helper.rb:29:in `block in nav_items'
App 98561 stderr:   app/helpers/navigation_helper.rb:28:in `map'
App 98561 stderr:   app/helpers/navigation_helper.rb:28:in `nav_items'
App 98561 stderr:   app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_layouts__navigation_html_erb__2164981464980004636_37092560'
App 98561 stderr:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:28:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1560657679497288447_36282840'
```

while in production.log no issue is registered (because logalhost:3000 works perfectly).
Any solutions, tips?

Comment: error is related to model not present, do you have table named `concepts`?

Comment: check your database migration . If you are using sqlite3, you may need to do `rake db:migrate` since the error says the table `concepts` is not present.

Comment: I discovered it was using the production db, which was empty. I got another problem now, but this one is solved. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by the use of the production db (at least in localhost/vocab), which was empty.

I verified from the command line with:

`sqlite3 db_name_production`
`.tables` - to check if the necessary tables are presents
`SELECT * FROM table_name;` - to check the data in a table

CTRL + D to exit from sqlite3

Then set the rails environment to production mode and migrate the tables

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` (if you are serving static assets)

And start passenger in production mode

`passenger start -e production`

This solution served the correct website on localhost/vocab/ but still present (i my case at least) issue in serving files (manifest.css/js)